# Couldn't generate 8dot3 name in particular folder on windows server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I was reported that our application can't generate 8.3 name in a particular folder.

The first thing pop up my mind is 8.3 creation setting probably is disabled.
[image]
Well, it was enabled. I modified the registry key and reboot too which didn't work either.

I found `dir /x` not able to show 8dot3 name in that path as well.
[image]

The weirdest thing I found is it only becomes invalid in this particular folder!
If I move to another folder in `D:` then the operation will work without problem. For instance, `D:\anotherfolder\PML_\18WW1PNL601.ini` will be converted to
`D:\anotherfolder\PML_\18WW1P~1.INI` correctly.

I wonder if it has something to do with permission but not sure where to start. I mean my account is admin already what else should I do?

---

I copy a new one as @barlop suggested. Surprisingly, it can generate 8.3 name successfully.
[image]
Furthermore, I found in `D:`. 8.3 creation only work on those folders and files created by me.
Still, don't know what's going on here.

Comment: It looks like you have an issue that some directories support 8.3 names while other directories on the same disk do not.  Please [edit] your question to focus on the behavior of ```dir /x``` and deemphasize the programming interface aspect.

Comment: no idea but what if now that you have enabled the 8.3 thing, if you `copy 18WW1PNL601.ini 28WW1PNL601.ini`  then do dir /x  will the new file show as 8.3 or not?

Comment: another thing to check is if you have any other folders where this is happening

Answer (score 2):

The reason for 8dot3names creation for particular folders is because these folders were created when the 8dot3name setting was enabled on the volume these folders exist in.

You can try this experiment by enabling this setting, then create a folder and try to obtain its short name.

You can read more about this from here:
[NTFS 8.3 short names](https://guyrleech.wordpress.com/2014/04/15/ntfs-8-3-short-names-solving-the-issues/)

As I've already been through this problem.